# Plot coordinates with different colours corresponding to class labels in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have a matrix `X` of shape `Nx2` and a corresponding set of labels (5 labels for 5 classes, eg., 0,1,2,3,4) in matrix `Y` of length `N`. Now I want to plot `X` using matplotlib scatter plot such that the value in `X` corresponding to each label in `Y` comes in a different colour. I'm not sure about the exact parameters of `plt.scatter()` for this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the colors parameter to `scatter`. If you simply pass the class label array as the color parameter, the colormap will be used to map each label to a corresponding RGB value.

```
plt.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], c=Y)
```